# How do clients handle JavaScript after they receive the "Location" HTTP header?

Tags: javascript, php, http, google-analytics, http-headers

Consider the code:

**somepage.php**

```
<?php header('Location: index.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script>
     doSomething(); // does the browser run this?
   </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I am trying to put Google Analytics there, but I am not sure if people are actually loading the analytics JS at all.

Does the browser actually look at the output after the `Location` header has been sent? If so, does it actually run the JavaScript?

Comment: That's incorrect. It sends the `Location:` header to the client, and the client performs the redirection.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: uh, no. the redirection occurs on the client, in response to the server sending it the location header.

Comment: @jason: you run into a race condition. Once the client receives the `Location` header, it MAY decide to load/process the rest of the page, or just ditch it entirely and immediately start redirecting. You can't guarantee that the JS script will be parsed at all, let alone executed.

Comment: My bad - I knew that. Just had my head in another place when I said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers ignore the response body when a redirect header is sent. So it won't display HTML, and it won't execute Javascript.

If you want to execute something before redirecting, don't use the `Location:` header. Send a page that executes the Javascript, and then executes

```
window.location.href = "index.php";
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I would have to do that.